# How do I add an author using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I try:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["torch", 'tensorflow']}


target = Executable(
    script='start.py',
)
setup(
    name='my',
    options={'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    author="me",
    executables=[target]
)
```

but when I check the copyright field in the file properties of `start.exe`, it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `version` field:

```py
setup(
    ...
    version='0.1',
    ...
)
```

otherwise the executable file properties are not created, as suggested by the warning:

> WARNING: unable to create version resource: version must be specified

The version needs to be [PEP440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/)-compliant, see [Specifying Your Project’s Version](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/distribution.html) in the `setuptools` documentation.